# windows authentication in win 8 apps

Tags: c#, xaml

I am developing a windows 8 app using c# and xaml. My app should be able to implement windows authentication so that it can allow the logged in user to launch the app. Can anyone help or give me a code snippet to solve this problem???

thanks in advance

Comment: Please rephrase your question. Users need to be logged in to launch the app in the first place - so I'm not sure what you want to do.

Comment: In my application I want to retrieve the username and password which he has entered while logging into the system.

Answer (score 3):

To Enable Windows Authentication in windows 8 App

Go to *Package.appxmanifest* file.

Go to *Capabilities* tab. Check the *Enterprise Authentication* feature on the Page.

Include the Namespace 
    **using Windows.System.UserProfile;**
Eg to Use the Profile User Name :
     *txtUserName.Text = await UserInformation.GetFirstNameAsync();*

This is how you will get the details of the Windows Authentication user.
Hope this helped you !

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. Windows 8 "Immersive" applications are sandboxed and have no access to Windows' own user management. In any event user passwords are hashed (a one-way transform), you can't read back the original passwords even if you had access to the SAM file.

If you want a user's Windows password you'll have to ask them up-front, but I gurantee no (intelligent) user would voluntarily agree to this, and chances are your application would be denied on the Windows app-store if you did submit it.